# What is going on with my JS?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to ask how I can add numbers to my input by clicking on the button and then deleting them by clicking on the button with `id="ff"`. Here is the code, when I am running it the button is appearing, but it isn't typing, just button `ff` is "turning on". And when I'm clicking it there are empty input, which can't work correctly.

```js
var screen = document.getElementById('tt');
var p = screen.InnerHTML;
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

if (p == '') {
  ff.style.display = 'none';
}

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    p += this.InnerHTML;
    if (p !== '') {
      ff.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
  })
}

var z = document.getElementById('ff');
z.onclick = function() {
  p = p.substring(0, p.length - 1);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.phone {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.screen {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white
}

#tt {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#ff {
  padding: 1%;
  display: none;
}

.buttons>div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.buttons>div>button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="phone">
    <div class="screen">
      <input type="text" id="tt">
      <input type="button" id="ff">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
      <div>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
        <button>6</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>7</button>
        <button>8</button>
        <button>9</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>*</button>
        <button>0</button>
        <button>#</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `innerHTML`, not `InnerHTML`, but that doesn't matter because `<input>` elements don't have any content. You're probably looking for `.value`.

Comment: Don't declare a global variable named `screen`. The browser already has this as a built-in global variable, it contains information about the computer screen.

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy said in the comments, it is `innerHTML`, not `InnerHTML`.

You can not use `innerHTML` for `input` tags; you can only use `value` (however, for the `button` tag, you can use `innerHTML`).

Change

```
var p = screen.InnerHTML;
```

To

```
var p = screen.value;
```

You are changing the value of the global variable `p` each time instead of `screen.value` which will actually change the `value` of the element to be displayed.

Change

```
p += this.InnerHTML;
if (p !== '') {
  ff.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

To

```
screen.value += this.InnerHTML;
if (screen.value !== '') {
  ff.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.phone {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.screen {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white
}

#tt {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#ff {
  padding: 1%;
  display: none;
}

.buttons>div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.buttons>div>button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="phone">
    <div class="screen">
      <input type="text" id="tt">
      <input type="button" id="ff">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
      <div>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
        <button>6</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>7</button>
        <button>8</button>
        <button>9</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>*</button>
        <button>0</button>
        <button>#</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var screen = document.getElementById('tt');
    var p = screen.value;
    var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    if (p == '') {
      ff.style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
      btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        screen.value += this.innerHTML;
        if (screen.value !== '') {
          ff.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
      })
    }
    var z = document.getElementById('ff');
    z.onclick = function() {
      screen.value = p.substring(0, p.length - 1);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made this corrections:

- `InnerHTML` is incorrect. I replaced with `innerHTML`, which is the correct form.
- Replaced `var p` with `screen.value`, in order to get the real value every time the var is called.

Now it works how it should:

```js
var screen = document.getElementById('tt');
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
if (screen.value == '') {
 ff.style.display = 'none';
}
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  screen.value += this.innerHTML;
  if (screen.value !== '') {
   ff.style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
 });
}
var z = document.getElementById('ff');
z.addEventListener('click', function(){
 screen.value = screen.value.substring(0, screen.value.length - 1);
});
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;  
}
.phone{
 width: 220px;
 height: 220px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
}
.screen{
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px;
 background: white
}
#tt{
 font-size: 2em; 
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#ff{
 padding: 1%;
 display: none;
}
.buttons>div{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 display: flex;
}
.buttons>div>button{
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="phone">
  <div class="screen">
   <input type="text" id="tt">
   <input type="button" id="ff">
  </div>

  <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
   <div>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <button>*</button>
    <button>0</button>
    <button>#</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">


</script>
</body>
</html>
```